# Disable Nvidia Control Panel from checking for updates

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, updates, nvidia-geforce

My graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GT 530. Drivers are currently at version 388.59. Attached monitor is a Dell U2410. OS is Windows 7, 64-bit.

The Nvidia Control Panel is handy, but it seems that it constantly presents the nag-box below to update drivers. Nvidia Control Panel version is the only Nvidia program running, and the driver update does not appear when this program is not started. Nvidia Control Panel version is 8.1.940.0.

**Is there any way to disable Nvidia Control Panel from checking for updates?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use Windows Firewall (or your choice of third-party firewall) to block the Nvidia Control Panel from having access to the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nvidia creates a number of scheduled tasks.  You can disable the task named `NvDriverUpdateCheckDaily_{GUID}` to disable the update checks.

To do so: Run `taskschd.msc` to launch the scheduled task MMC snap-in, locate the task as shown below and disable it.  It can be enabled again at a later time or run manually as required.

[image: Nvidia scheduled task]

**Note**: At the time of writing, the command launched by this task is as follows:

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvContainer\nvcontainer.exe
>   -d "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvDriverUpdateCheck" -l 3 -f C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA\NvContainerDriverUpdateCheck.log

**Another note:** To prove to yourself that this really works for your setup, disable the task and restart the computer. If you Enable, and then Run the task, the update reminder should show up immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The [first answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1288165/disable-nvidia-control-panel-from-checking-for-updates/1288807#1288807) from [HelpingHand](https://superuser.com/users/682835/helpinghand) was extremely good.

It was so good, that I thought the issue was gone completely. For many days *(weeks?)* the NVIDIA nag-box was gone. And then one day it popped up again as soon as I logged on.

In addition to the tasks in the Windows "Task Scheduler", I also had to disable several NVIDIA services. You can do this using:

- Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
- Run > `services.msc`
- Run > `msconfig` > "Services" tab

System service that must be **enabled** for the NVIDIA Control Panel to work:

```
NVIDIA Display Container LS
```

System services that can be **disabled**:

```
NVIDIA LocalSystem Container
NVIDIA NetworkService Container
NVIDIA Telemetry Container
```

[image]

Complete list of tasks in "Task Scheduler" that can be disabled:

```
NvDriverUpdateCheckDaily_{GUID}
NVIDIA GeForce Experience SelfUpdate_{GUID}
NvNodeLauncher_{GUID}
NvProfileUpdaterDaily_{GUID}
NvProfileUpdaterOnLogon_{GUID}
NvTmMon_{GUID}
NvTmRep_{GUID}
NvTmRepOnLogon_{GUID}
```

[image]